# Limit of probability(fair coin)

Tags: probability, limits

The expression,
$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left( \begin{matrix} 2n \\ n \end{matrix} \right) \frac { 1 }{ { 2 }^{ 2n } }  } $$ denotes the probability of obtaining n heads in 2n tosses of a fair coin. Hence, the expression should evaluate to 1. But the expression actually evaluates to 0. So where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your error is in thinking that the exact number of heads should go to half the number of flips.  The expected *proportion* does indeed go to $1/2$, but the probability of *exactly* half of the (even number of) flips coming up heads goes to $0$, as you observe.

Comment: It shouldn't evaluate to 1. The intuition: when you throw a dice 1M times, you have a low probability to get exactly 500,000 heads, since you can also have 500,001 and 500,002 and so on, all almost as likely.

Comment: $0$ is the correct value. You have done nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using algebra
$$a_n=2^{-2 n} \binom{2 n}{n}=2^{-2 n}\frac{(2n)!}{[n!]^2}\implies \log(a_n)=-2n \log(2)+\log((2n)!)-2\log(n!)$$

Use Stirling approximation to get
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left({\pi  n}\right)-\frac{1}{8 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n} }\left(1-\frac 1 {8n} \right)$$

Another way is to use the approximation
$$\binom{2 n}{n}\sim \frac {4^n} {\sqrt{\pi n}}=\frac {2^{2n}} {\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Comment: To see why the expression goes to zero, the simple way to see would be that 2nCn is a polynomial of degree at most n. Hence, applying L'hopital's rule n+1 times, we see that degree of numerator decreases every time, and the degree of the exponential doesn't decrease. So the limit obviously evaluates to 0. Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.